# Can carriers limit UDP traffic?

Tags: networking, blackberry, mobile, java-me, udp

Is it possible and is there such a practice?

I am making an application which works well with udp over wifi but fails over 3G networks. It could very well be some platform limitation or error in my code but I am wondering if it is possible to have limitation on using UDP imposed by the carrier.

The application is for the Blackberry platform.

Comment: It's possibly (likely) you just have higher packet loss on 3G than on WiFi generally, for UDP and TCP alike

Comment: It would helpful to know more about what you are doing.  Are UDP packets originating from the device to some server somewhere, or the other direction?  How big are the packets?  What port are you using?  Do any packets get through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically possibly for them to limit UDP, but unlikely that they would. As already mentioned, you are probably just experiencing high packet loss.

Is this a streaming application? If not, you could consider using TCP instead to assure delivery.

Comment: Yes it is a streaming application and it turned out that I was experiencing problems due to bad connection and some faulty implementaion on my side. However thanks for the information - it is useful to know this.